# How to delete duplicate record which has one unique column

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a table like this.

[image]

How can I remove the records "Jimmy" and "Kenneth" which has greater Month values.

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on the **database** you are using, can you **TAG** it

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to add it. It is Sql Server. I've tagged it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from tablename t1 where exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                                       where t1.name = t2.name
                                         and t1.month > t2.month)
```

But why doesn't take year into consideration? Why not use a date datatype?
What if two Jimmys from same month?
Why no unique constraint if no duplicates allowed?

Comment: You're right. Year must be considered. I just tried to make it more clear and simple.

Answer (score 4):

Use `CTE` to delete the duplicate records

```
;with cte as
(
select Rn=row_number()over(partition by name,post order by month ASC),* 
from yourtable 
)
delete from cte where rn>1
```

Answer (score 2):

if month is a column of numbers try this :

```
DELETE table
WHERE  month = (SELECT Max(month)
                FROM   table
                WHERE  name = 'Jimmy')
       AND name = 'Jimmy';

DELETE table
WHERE  month = (SELECT Max(month)
                FROM   table
                WHERE  name = 'Kenneth')
       AND name = 'Kenneth';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use over partition to seperate the biggest values in Month:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY name, Post
                   ORDER BY Month DESC) AS RowNumber
        FROM   TABLE)
WHERE  rownumber = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code..

```
WITH tblTemp as(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() Over(PARTITION BY Name,Post ORDER BY Name)As RowNumber,* FROM <table_name>)DELETE FROM tblTemp where RowNumber >1
```